# Get all items from list1 that don't exist in list2

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists in c#.
I need to find the cutting between them. (all the items from list1 that don't exist in list2). I want use on linq.
How can I do it ?

Comment: This question was answered a hundred times on SO. And it does not even show  minimum effort, neither by showing what you have tried nor by providing sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

Example from *MSDN* page;

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
         Console.WriteLine(number);

/*
This code produces the following output:

2
2.1
2.3
2.4
2.5
*/
```

As Tim Schmelter *[pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230006/get-all-items-from-list1-that-dont-exist-in-list2#comment31977141_21230037)*, if you want to use this method on your custom data types, you need to implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and you need to provide `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods..

Comment: It is worth noting that it does not work on custom types without providing a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I sometimes do not understand what is the difference between questions which do not show ANY attempts (even in words, not code) that some are answered and other closed as "unclear what you're asking"... Is it going to be "I want code to do this and that, write me it" portal?

Comment: @KonradKokosa There's [a lot of confusion and frustration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason) with the new set of Close Vote reasons.

Comment: @KonradKokosa Who said I didn't vote to close? `:)` This question doesn't show any effort or course. But sometimes that doesn't mean I don't want to answer `;)`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, in my humble opinion it is not about Close Vote reasons but about people's hunger to get reputation from such a effortless, duplicated and basic questions... I know it is tempting, I fight with it too, but come on.. this question is the Mount Everest of effortless and laziness.. ;)

Comment: @KonradKokosa It's about both. Not being able to *find* a valid reason implies (and is somewhat confirmed by the moderators) that the question then *shouldn't* be closed. Which is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ functions in `Enumerable` are nice, but sometimes you should make sure you're using the right data structures, which often include relevant operations.

In this case, it sounds like you're working with [*sets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29).  These are often implemented  with [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for efficiency. .NET provides such a data structure with [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

The function used to get the difference between one set and another (which is what you're asking) is [`HashSet<T>.ExceptWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx).

The example from that page goes like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    HashSet<int> lowNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
    HashSet<int> highNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        lowNumbers.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++)
    {
        highNumbers.Add(i);
    }

    Console.Write("lowNumbers contains {0} elements: ", lowNumbers.Count);
    DisplaySet(lowNumbers);

    Console.Write("highNumbers contains {0} elements: ", highNumbers.Count);
    DisplaySet(highNumbers);

    Console.WriteLine("highNumbers ExceptWith lowNumbers...");
    highNumbers.ExceptWith(lowNumbers);

    Console.Write("highNumbers contains {0} elements: ", highNumbers.Count);
    DisplaySet(highNumbers);
}
/* This example provides output similar to the following:
 * lowNumbers contains 6 elements: { 0 1 2 3 4 5 }
 * highNumbers contains 7 elements: { 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
 * highNumbers ExceptWith lowNumbers...
 * highNumbers contains 4 elements: { 6 7 8 9 }
 */
```